# Passing multiple parameters to single stored procedure - DevExpress Dashboard Module

Tags: devexpress, dotnetnuke

We are using DevExpress controls for our DNN website since long time.

Now based on user requests, we are in process of creating Dashboard using DevExpress Dashboard module.

To make illustration, we created dashboard using

- Combobox (multi select)
- Grid
- BarChart

We also created a stored procedure with 2 parameters (from combobox and grid) and returning data for BarChart.

The issue is, we can't pass 2 parameters. Seems parameters are mismatching and one parameter is always 0.

[image]

As shown in above image,
`SelectedActivityTypeID` is passed as `SelectedSerial` (which supposed to string type with actual data), and `SelectedActivityTypeID` is always 0.

Can you please help us to understand how we can overcome this issue?

Any reference link or URL to documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič we are using dashboard module(GUI) for devexpress (so no code required)